# Asp.Net page rendering and UI controls modularity

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

the website I'm currently developing can display dynamically-built forms.

A `form` is composed of `fields`, which are created directly by the users and can be displayed as one of multiple types that we support (text box, list box, tickbox, radiobuttonlist etc.). The rendering logic uses a `repeater` that iterates over a collection of all the fields defined by the user.

Inside the repeater (directly in the aspx page), one instance of each of the types we support is defined.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="fieldRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox" runat="server" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox" runat="server" />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioButtonList" runat="server" />
        [...]
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

During the loading, we figure out which control is required and actively hide all the other ones.

Being still new to the web based development world, this approach seems very odd to me. My guts would prefer keeping the UI clean and instanciate exactly the controls that are required in CodeBehind and not start "playing" with visibility... but the current approach has some obvious benefits as well.

Is it really how one would do it in a web app?
Are there some best practices here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the best practice is here, but I have done something similar before in a previous project and tried both approaches.  Both will work.

Creating the controls in code-behind can be fiddly, especially if you are having to deal with post-backs.  The controls have to be created in OnInit, as otherwise they won't get the posted form values and viewstate populated.  This will cause complications if any of the control creation is based on the values of other controls, as you won't known the values without manually delving into the posted form values.

The only practical disadvantage with your current approach that I can think of is that all four controls (TextBox, DropDownList etc.) have to be instantiated and processed server-side by ASP.Net, which is a bit of a waste of resources.  But it's probably not too significant; maybe do some profiling to see.  I do agree that it seems a bit odd though, it doesn't feel very "clean".

As you said you're new to web development, then I would recommend continuing with your current approach of including all the controls and hiding the irrelevant ones.  I just found it simpler when I did, even though it may not seem as nice.

Good luck!